# Webpack Bootstrap 4 copy custom.scss file to node_modules

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

**Background:**
Bootstrap 4 has a file called _custom.scss where you can override the variables for the bootstrap framework for a custom theme.

I was able to get this working using gulp by copying a file in my project called "bootstrap-overrides.scss" and replacing the "_custom.scss" file with it's contents prior to compiling it. That solved my problems (using gulp).

**Issue:**
I am now trying to accomplish the same thing using webpack and I am having issues. I need this to happen BEFORE any of the bundling begins. ***All I need to do is copy "./source/bootstrap-overrides.scss" to "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss".***

I tried to accomplish this using the *copy-webpack-plugin*; however, it keeps dumping my files into the output path directory instead of the node_modules folder.

Any webpack gurus out there have any advice on how to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using the copy-webpack-plugin.

The key is to use an absolute path, rather than a relative path. Using path.join(__dirname, "path") will use an absolute path.

**Example:**

```
new copy_webpack_plugin([
  {
    from: path.join(__dirname, "source/styles/bootstrap-overrides.scss"),
    to: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_custom.scss")
  }
])
```